# GeForce Now en Linux (mediante Lutris)

Tags: linux, windows, shell, terminal, aplicación-escritorio

Estoy intentando ejecutar la aplicación de GeForce Now que se instala mediante Lutris en mi PC (con Linux) y cambie la "wine version" a la que sea, sigue fallando (por defecto la que instala es: "lutris-gfn-6-x86_64")

- DXVK Version: "1.7.2L-5ca255d"

Cuando ejecuto la aplicación consigue aparecer momentáneamente una ventana negra, pero desaparece al instante.

Dejo el log por si alguien sabe como interpretarlo bien y corregir este error.

Esto aparece después de ejecutar y darle al boton "show log" de la aplicación Lutris, por lo que entiendo que falta alguna librería, codec o algo así en lo que se instala, pero no puedo adivinar nada más:

```
Running gamemoderun /home/carlos/.local/share/lutris/runners/wine/lutris-gfn-6-x86_64/bin/wine /home/carlos/Games/geforce-now/drive_c/users/carlos/Local Settings/Application Data/NVIDIA Corporation/GeForceNOW/CEF/GeForceNOW.exe
Initial process has started with pid 6136
Game is considered started.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/$LIB/libgamemodeauto.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/$LIB/libgamemodeauto.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/$LIB/libgamemodeauto.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/$LIB/libgamemodeauto.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
wine: configuration in L"/home/carlos/Games/geforce-now" has been updated.
info:  Game: GeForceNOW.exe
info:  DXVK: v1.7.2-5-g13052d49
info:  Built-in extension providers:
info:    Win32 WSI
info:    OpenVR
warn:  OpenVR: Failed to locate module
info:  Enabled instance extensions:
info:    VK_KHR_get_surface_capabilities2
info:    VK_KHR_surface
info:    VK_KHR_win32_surface
info:  GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER:
info:    Driver: 450.80.2
info:    Vulkan: 1.2.133
info:    Memory Heap[0]: 
info:      Size: 8192 MiB
info:      Flags: 0x1
info:      Memory Type[7]: Property Flags = 0x1
info:    Memory Heap[1]: 
info:      Size: 11946 MiB
info:      Flags: 0x0
info:      Memory Type[0]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[1]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[2]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[3]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[4]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[5]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[6]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[8]: Property Flags = 0x6
info:      Memory Type[9]: Property Flags = 0xe
info:    Memory Heap[2]: 
info:      Size: 246 MiB
info:      Flags: 0x1
info:      Memory Type[10]: Property Flags = 0x7
info:  D3D11CoreCreateDevice: Probing 49152
info:  D3D11CoreCreateDevice: Probing D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1
info:  D3D11CoreCreateDevice: Using feature level D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1
info:  Device properties:
info:    Device name:     : GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER
info:    Driver version   : 450.80.2
info:  Enabled device extensions:
info:    VK_EXT_custom_border_color
info:    VK_EXT_depth_clip_enable
info:    VK_EXT_host_query_reset
info:    VK_EXT_shader_demote_to_helper_invocation
info:    VK_EXT_shader_viewport_index_layer
info:    VK_EXT_transform_feedback
info:    VK_EXT_vertex_attribute_divisor
info:    VK_KHR_create_renderpass2
info:    VK_KHR_depth_stencil_resolve
info:    VK_KHR_draw_indirect_count
info:    VK_KHR_driver_properties
info:    VK_KHR_image_format_list
info:    VK_KHR_sampler_mirror_clamp_to_edge
info:    VK_KHR_swapchain
info:  Device features:
info:    robustBufferAccess                     : 1
info:    fullDrawIndexUint32                    : 1
info:    imageCubeArray                         : 1
info:    independentBlend                       : 1
info:    geometryShader                         : 1
info:    tessellationShader                     : 1
info:    sampleRateShading                      : 1
info:    dualSrcBlend                           : 1
info:    logicOp                                : 1
info:    multiDrawIndirect                      : 1
info:    drawIndirectFirstInstance              : 1
info:    depthClamp                             : 1
info:    depthBiasClamp                         : 1
info:    fillModeNonSolid                       : 1
info:    depthBounds                            : 1
info:    multiViewport                          : 1
info:    samplerAnisotropy                      : 1
info:    textureCompressionBC                   : 1
info:    occlusionQueryPrecise                  : 1
info:    pipelineStatisticsQuery                : 1
info:    vertexPipelineStoresAndAtomics         : 1
info:    fragmentStoresAndAtomics               : 1
info:    shaderImageGatherExtended              : 1
info:    shaderStorageImageExtendedFormats      : 1
info:    shaderStorageImageReadWithoutFormat    : 1
info:    shaderStorageImageWriteWithoutFormat   : 1
info:    shaderClipDistance                     : 1
info:    shaderCullDistance                     : 1
info:    shaderFloat64                          : 1
info:    shaderInt64                            : 1
info:    variableMultisampleRate                : 1
info:  VK_EXT_conditional_rendering
info:    conditionalRendering                   : 1
info:  VK_EXT_4444_formats
info:    formatA4R4G4B4                         : 0
info:    formatA4B4G4R4                         : 0
info:  VK_EXT_custom_border_color
info:    customBorderColors                     : 1
info:    customBorderColorWithoutFormat         : 1
info:  VK_EXT_depth_clip_enable
info:    depthClipEnable                        : 1
info:  VK_EXT_extended_dynamic_state
info:    extendedDynamicState                   : 0
info:  VK_EXT_host_query_reset
info:    hostQueryReset                         : 1
info:  VK_EXT_memory_priority
info:    memoryPriority                         : 0
info:  VK_EXT_robustness2
info:    robustBufferAccess2                    : 0
info:    robustImageAccess2                     : 0
info:    nullDescriptor                         : 0
info:  VK_EXT_shader_demote_to_helper_invocation
info:    shaderDemoteToHelperInvocation         : 1
info:  VK_EXT_transform_feedback
info:    transformFeedback                      : 1
info:    geometryStreams                        : 1
info:  VK_EXT_vertex_attribute_divisor
info:    vertexAttributeInstanceRateDivisor     : 1
info:    vertexAttributeInstanceRateZeroDivisor : 1
info:  Queue families:
info:    Graphics : 0
info:    Transfer : 1
info:  DXVK: Read 0 valid state cache entries
info:  DXVK: Using 2 compiler threads
info:  DXGI: NvAPI workaround enabled, reporting AMD GPU
info:  Adapter LUID 0: 0:400
err:   D3D11DXGIResource::CreateSharedHandle: Stub
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:27.547:ERROR:network_change_notifier_win.cc(142)] WSALookupServiceBegin failed with: 0
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:27.834:INFO:browser_app.cc(408)] Framework Microsoft Windows 64bit
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:27.834:INFO:browser_app.cc(412)] Version NVIDIACEFClient/84.4147.89.1/gfn_release/4996f0d2b
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:27.834:INFO:browser_app.cc(742)] No urlRoute value found.
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:27.836:INFO:simple_grid_app.cc(52)] Creating SimpleGridApp
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:27.894:INFO:cef_plugin_win.cpp(28)] Loaded dependency module CrimsonUtil.dll
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.172:INFO:rtsp_handler_win.cc(69)] Serenity: RTSP interface is ready for ShareServer.dll
info:  Game: GeForceNOW.exe
info:  DXVK: v1.7.2-5-g13052d49
info:  Built-in extension providers:
info:    Win32 WSI
info:    OpenVR
warn:  OpenVR: Failed to locate module
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.196:INFO:rtsp_handler_win.cc(69)] Serenity: RTSP interface is ready for gfnspfbc.dll
info:  Enabled instance extensions:
info:    VK_KHR_get_surface_capabilities2
info:    VK_KHR_surface
info:    VK_KHR_win32_surface
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.241:INFO:rtsp_handler_win.cc(69)] Serenity: RTSP interface is ready for NvCamera.dll
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.242:INFO:browser_app.cc(834)] Geronimo Logger Init
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.242:INFO:geronimo_logger.cpp(20)] Creating GeronimoLogger
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.243:INFO:browser_app.cc(839)] shared storage path for geronimo C:\users\carlos\Local Settings\Application Data\NVIDIA Corporation\GeForceNOW\sharedstorage.json
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.243:INFO:browser_app.cc(845)] Geronimo SDL Init
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.250:INFO:geronimo_analytics.cpp(16)] Creating GeronimoDispatcher
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.250:INFO:browser_app.cc(859)] Geronimo Tracing Init
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.251:INFO:browser_app.cc(862)] Geronimo GRID Init
I-!#>
 [2020-11-01 10:11:28,254]=11:11:28=    INFO [Common: Network] {00000168} - BCryptGenRandom succeeded
I-!#>
 [2020-11-01 10:11:28,255]=11:11:28=    INFO [Common: Network] {00000168} - Successfully set overridden random method
I-!$> [2020-11-01 10:11:28,254]=11:11:28=    INFO [BifrostClient: Scheduler] {00000264} - Successfully set TLS with value 000000000F1D24F0
I-!$> [2020-11-01 10:11:28,254]=11:11:28=    INFO [BifrostClient: Scheduler] {00000268} - Successfully set TLS with value 000000000F1D24F0
I-!$> [2020-11-01 10:11:28,256]=11:11:28=   DEBUG [BifrostClient: Interface] {00000168} - nvbCreateClient( 000000000F1D1710 )
info:  GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER:
info:    Driver: 450.80.2
info:    Vulkan: 1.2.133
info:    Memory Heap[0]: 
info:      Size: 8192 MiB
info:      Flags: 0x1
info:      Memory Type[7]: Property Flags = 0x1
info:    Memory Heap[1]: 
info:      Size: 11946 MiB
info:      Flags: 0x0
info:      Memory Type[0]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[1]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[2]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[3]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[4]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[5]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[6]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[8]: Property Flags = 0x6
info:      Memory Type[9]: Property Flags = 0xe
info:    Memory Heap[2]: 
info:      Size: 246 MiB
info:      Flags: 0x1
info:      Memory Type[10]: Property Flags = 0x7
info:  DXGI: NvAPI workaround enabled, reporting AMD GPU
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.259:INFO:browser_app.cc(872)] Grid interface is 000000000F22DBE0
info:  Adapter LUID 0: 0:402
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.259:INFO:offscreen_sdlwindow_mgr.cpp(30)] Creating SWindowManager
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.259:INFO:offscreen_sdlwindow_mgr.cpp(43)] Before SWindowManager::init(), m_eprocessor is 0000000000000000
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.271:ERROR:dxva_video_decode_accelerator_win.cc(1431)] DXVAVDA fatal error: could not LoadLibrary: msmpeg2vdec.dll: Mdulo no encontrado. (0x7E)
info:  Game: GeForceNOW.exe
info:  DXVK: v1.7.2-5-g13052d49
info:  Built-in extension providers:
info:    Win32 WSI
info:    OpenVR
warn:  OpenVR: Failed to locate module
info:  Enabled instance extensions:
info:    VK_KHR_get_surface_capabilities2
info:    VK_KHR_surface
info:    VK_KHR_win32_surface
info:  GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER:
info:    Driver: 450.80.2
info:    Vulkan: 1.2.133
info:    Memory Heap[0]: 
info:      Size: 8192 MiB
info:      Flags: 0x1
info:      Memory Type[7]: Property Flags = 0x1
info:    Memory Heap[1]: 
info:      Size: 11946 MiB
info:      Flags: 0x0
info:      Memory Type[0]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[1]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[2]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[3]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[4]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[5]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[6]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[8]: Property Flags = 0x6
info:      Memory Type[9]: Property Flags = 0xe
info:    Memory Heap[2]: 
info:      Size: 246 MiB
info:      Flags: 0x1
info:      Memory Type[10]: Property Flags = 0x7
info:  D3D11CoreCreateDevice: Probing D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1
info:  D3D11CoreCreateDevice: Using feature level D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1
info:  Device properties:
info:    Device name:     : GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER
info:    Driver version   : 450.80.2
info:  Enabled device extensions:
info:    VK_EXT_custom_border_color
info:    VK_EXT_depth_clip_enable
info:    VK_EXT_host_query_reset
info:    VK_EXT_shader_demote_to_helper_invocation
info:    VK_EXT_shader_viewport_index_layer
info:    VK_EXT_transform_feedback
info:    VK_EXT_vertex_attribute_divisor
info:    VK_KHR_create_renderpass2
info:    VK_KHR_depth_stencil_resolve
info:    VK_KHR_draw_indirect_count
info:    VK_KHR_driver_properties
info:    VK_KHR_image_format_list
info:    VK_KHR_sampler_mirror_clamp_to_edge
info:    VK_KHR_swapchain
info:  Device features:
info:    robustBufferAccess                     : 1
info:    fullDrawIndexUint32                    : 1
info:    imageCubeArray                         : 1
info:    independentBlend                       : 1
info:    geometryShader                         : 1
info:    tessellationShader                     : 1
info:    sampleRateShading                      : 1
info:    dualSrcBlend                           : 1
info:    logicOp                                : 1
info:    multiDrawIndirect                      : 1
info:    drawIndirectFirstInstance              : 1
info:    depthClamp                             : 1
info:    depthBiasClamp                         : 1
info:    fillModeNonSolid                       : 1
info:    depthBounds                            : 1
info:    multiViewport                          : 1
info:    samplerAnisotropy                      : 1
info:    textureCompressionBC                   : 1
info:    occlusionQueryPrecise                  : 1
info:    pipelineStatisticsQuery                : 1
info:    vertexPipelineStoresAndAtomics         : 1
info:    fragmentStoresAndAtomics               : 1
info:    shaderImageGatherExtended              : 1
info:    shaderStorageImageExtendedFormats      : 1
info:    shaderStorageImageReadWithoutFormat    : 1
info:    shaderStorageImageWriteWithoutFormat   : 1
info:    shaderClipDistance                     : 1
info:    shaderCullDistance                     : 1
info:    shaderFloat64                          : 1
info:    shaderInt64                            : 1
info:    variableMultisampleRate                : 1
info:  VK_EXT_conditional_rendering
info:    conditionalRendering                   : 1
info:  VK_EXT_4444_formats
info:    formatA4R4G4B4                         : 0
info:    formatA4B4G4R4                         : 0
info:  VK_EXT_custom_border_color
info:    customBorderColors                     : 1
info:    customBorderColorWithoutFormat         : 1
info:  VK_EXT_depth_clip_enable
info:    depthClipEnable                        : 1
info:  VK_EXT_extended_dynamic_state
info:    extendedDynamicState                   : 0
info:  VK_EXT_host_query_reset
info:    hostQueryReset                         : 1
info:  VK_EXT_memory_priority
info:    memoryPriority                         : 0
info:  VK_EXT_robustness2
info:    robustBufferAccess2                    : 0
info:    robustImageAccess2                     : 0
info:    nullDescriptor                         : 0
info:  VK_EXT_shader_demote_to_helper_invocation
info:    shaderDemoteToHelperInvocation         : 1
info:  VK_EXT_transform_feedback
info:    transformFeedback                      : 1
info:    geometryStreams                        : 1
info:  VK_EXT_vertex_attribute_divisor
info:    vertexAttributeInstanceRateDivisor     : 1
info:    vertexAttributeInstanceRateZeroDivisor : 1
info:  Queue families:
info:    Graphics : 0
info:    Transfer : 1
info:  DXVK: Read 0 valid state cache entries
info:  DXVK: Using 2 compiler threads
info:  DXGI: NvAPI workaround enabled, reporting AMD GPU
info:  Game: GeForceNOW.exe
info:  DXVK: v1.7.2-5-g13052d49
info:  Built-in extension providers:
info:    Win32 WSI
info:    OpenVR
warn:  OpenVR: Failed to locate module
info:  Enabled instance extensions:
info:    VK_KHR_get_surface_capabilities2
info:    VK_KHR_surface
info:    VK_KHR_win32_surface
warn:  D3D9: VK_FORMAT_D16_UNORM_S8_UINT -> VK_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT
warn:  D3D9: VK_FORMAT_A4R4G4B4_UNORM_PACK16_EXT -> VK_FORMAT_B4G4R4A4_UNORM_PACK16
info:  GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER:
info:    Driver: 450.80.2
info:    Vulkan: 1.2.133
info:    Memory Heap[0]: 
info:      Size: 8192 MiB
info:      Flags: 0x1
info:      Memory Type[7]: Property Flags = 0x1
info:    Memory Heap[1]: 
info:      Size: 11946 MiB
info:      Flags: 0x0
info:      Memory Type[0]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[1]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[2]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[3]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[4]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[5]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[6]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[8]: Property Flags = 0x6
info:      Memory Type[9]: Property Flags = 0xe
info:    Memory Heap[2]: 
info:      Size: 246 MiB
info:      Flags: 0x1
info:      Memory Type[10]: Property Flags = 0x7
info:  Process set as DPI aware
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.446:INFO:offscreen_sdlwindow_mgr.cpp(105)] Init SDL Event Processor, m_eprocessor is 000000000F27C330
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.446:INFO:offscreen_sdlwindow_mgr.cpp(125)] In exit of SWindowManager::init() m_eprocessor is 000000000F27C330
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.446:INFO:browser_app.cc(58)] Creating SGamepad
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.454:INFO:cef_plugin_manager.cpp(25)] Creating CefPluginManager
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.454:INFO:browser_app.cc(995)] CreateCefWindowInstance
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.454:INFO:query_handler.cc(33)] Creating QueryHandler
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.454:INFO:osr_query_handler.cc(21)] Creating OSRQueryHandler
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.454:INFO:gfn_query_handler.cc(48)] Creating GFNQueryHandler
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.454:INFO:simple_handler.cc(43)] Creating SimpleHandler
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.454:INFO:osr_simple_handler.cpp(37)] Creating OSRSimpleHandler
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.454:INFO:browser_app.cc(999)] Add handler 000000000F28B930
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.455:INFO:cef_window.cpp(59)] Creating cef_window
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.455:INFO:cef_dark_window.cpp(191)] Creating cef_dark_window
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.455:INFO:cef_dark_aero_window.cpp(203)] Creating cef_dark_aero_window
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.455:INFO:cef_dark_window.cpp(244)] GDI+ startup
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.480:INFO:cef_dark_window.cpp(827)] Could not get browser reference while drawing system icons
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.483:INFO:cef_dark_window.cpp(827)] Could not get browser reference while drawing system icons
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.488:INFO:cef_dark_window.cpp(827)] Could not get browser reference while drawing system icons
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.492:INFO:cef_dark_window.cpp(827)] Could not get browser reference while drawing system icons
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.494:INFO:cef_dark_window.cpp(827)] Could not get browser reference while drawing system icons
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.531:INFO:offscreen_sdlwindow.cpp(44)] Creating SWindow
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.531:INFO:offscreen_sdlwindow_mgr.cpp(179)] SDLWindowMgr createWindow callback for 000000000F2DB1A0
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.550:INFO:cef_dark_window.cpp(827)] Could not get browser reference while drawing system icons
warn:  winevulkan detected, disabling exclusive fullscreen support
info:  Presenter: Actual swap chain properties:
info:    Format:       VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM
info:    Present mode: VK_PRESENT_MODE_IMMEDIATE_KHR
info:    Buffer size:  1240x773
info:    Image count:  3
info:    Exclusive FS: 2
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.679:INFO:simple_grid_app.cc(797)] sendAnalyticsEvent(Debug, , )
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.679:INFO:simple_grid_app.cc(315)] No GridApp callback found
warn:  DXGI: MakeWindowAssociation: Ignoring flags
info:  Presenter: Actual swap chain properties:
info:    Format:       VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM
info:    Present mode: VK_PRESENT_MODE_FIFO_KHR
info:    Buffer size:  1240x773
info:    Image count:  3
info:    Exclusive FS: 2
```

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no es de programación

Comment: Por favor leer [ask]. Tu pregunta no se ajusta a la temática del sitio, tal como se establece en el [help/on-topic]. Saludos

Answer (score -1):

*Segunda mitad del log, que las restricciones del post no me dejaron hacerlo de una.

```
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.774:INFO:osr_simple_handler.cpp(90)] Add window 000000000F2DB1A0
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.775:INFO:cef_dark_window.cpp(827)] Could not get browser reference while drawing system icons
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.780:INFO:cef_dark_window.cpp(827)] Could not get browser reference while drawing system icons
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.782:INFO:cef_dark_window.cpp(827)] Could not get browser reference while drawing system icons
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.785:INFO:offscreen_window.cpp(61)] Creating OSRWindow
info:  Game: GeForceNOW.exe
info:  DXVK: v1.7.2-5-g13052d49
info:  Built-in extension providers:
info:    Win32 WSI
info:    OpenVR
warn:  OpenVR: Failed to locate module
info:  Enabled instance extensions:
info:    VK_KHR_get_surface_capabilities2
info:    VK_KHR_surface
info:    VK_KHR_win32_surface
info:  GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER:
info:    Driver: 450.80.2
info:    Vulkan: 1.2.133
info:    Memory Heap[0]: 
info:      Size: 8192 MiB
info:      Flags: 0x1
info:      Memory Type[7]: Property Flags = 0x1
info:    Memory Heap[1]: 
info:      Size: 11946 MiB
info:      Flags: 0x0
info:      Memory Type[0]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[1]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[2]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[3]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[4]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[5]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[6]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[8]: Property Flags = 0x6
info:      Memory Type[9]: Property Flags = 0xe
info:    Memory Heap[2]: 
info:      Size: 246 MiB
info:      Flags: 0x1
info:      Memory Type[10]: Property Flags = 0x7
info:  D3D11CoreCreateDevice: Probing 49152
info:  D3D11CoreCreateDevice: Probing D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1
info:  D3D11CoreCreateDevice: Using feature level D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1
info:  Device properties:
info:    Device name:     : GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER
info:    Driver version   : 450.80.2
info:  Enabled device extensions:
info:    VK_EXT_custom_border_color
info:    VK_EXT_depth_clip_enable
info:    VK_EXT_host_query_reset
info:    VK_EXT_shader_demote_to_helper_invocation
info:    VK_EXT_shader_viewport_index_layer
info:    VK_EXT_transform_feedback
info:    VK_EXT_vertex_attribute_divisor
info:    VK_KHR_create_renderpass2
info:    VK_KHR_depth_stencil_resolve
info:    VK_KHR_draw_indirect_count
info:    VK_KHR_driver_properties
info:    VK_KHR_image_format_list
info:    VK_KHR_sampler_mirror_clamp_to_edge
info:    VK_KHR_swapchain
info:  Device features:
info:    robustBufferAccess                     : 1
info:    fullDrawIndexUint32                    : 1
info:    imageCubeArray                         : 1
info:    independentBlend                       : 1
info:    geometryShader                         : 1
info:    tessellationShader                     : 1
info:    sampleRateShading                      : 1
info:    dualSrcBlend                           : 1
info:    logicOp                                : 1
info:    multiDrawIndirect                      : 1
info:    drawIndirectFirstInstance              : 1
info:    depthClamp                             : 1
info:    depthBiasClamp                         : 1
info:    fillModeNonSolid                       : 1
info:    depthBounds                            : 1
info:    multiViewport                          : 1
info:    samplerAnisotropy                      : 1
info:    textureCompressionBC                   : 1
info:    occlusionQueryPrecise                  : 1
info:    pipelineStatisticsQuery                : 1
info:    vertexPipelineStoresAndAtomics         : 1
info:    fragmentStoresAndAtomics               : 1
info:    shaderImageGatherExtended              : 1
info:    shaderStorageImageExtendedFormats      : 1
info:    shaderStorageImageReadWithoutFormat    : 1
info:    shaderStorageImageWriteWithoutFormat   : 1
info:    shaderClipDistance                     : 1
info:    shaderCullDistance                     : 1
info:    shaderFloat64                          : 1
info:    shaderInt64                            : 1
info:    variableMultisampleRate                : 1
info:  VK_EXT_conditional_rendering
info:    conditionalRendering                   : 1
info:  VK_EXT_4444_formats
info:    formatA4R4G4B4                         : 0
info:    formatA4B4G4R4                         : 0
info:  VK_EXT_custom_border_color
info:    customBorderColors                     : 1
info:    customBorderColorWithoutFormat         : 1
info:  VK_EXT_depth_clip_enable
info:    depthClipEnable                        : 1
info:  VK_EXT_extended_dynamic_state
info:    extendedDynamicState                   : 0
info:  VK_EXT_host_query_reset
info:    hostQueryReset                         : 1
info:  VK_EXT_memory_priority
info:    memoryPriority                         : 0
info:  VK_EXT_robustness2
info:    robustBufferAccess2                    : 0
info:    robustImageAccess2                     : 0
info:    nullDescriptor                         : 0
info:  VK_EXT_shader_demote_to_helper_invocation
info:    shaderDemoteToHelperInvocation         : 1
info:  VK_EXT_transform_feedback
info:    transformFeedback                      : 1
info:    geometryStreams                        : 1
info:  VK_EXT_vertex_attribute_divisor
info:    vertexAttributeInstanceRateDivisor     : 1
info:    vertexAttributeInstanceRateZeroDivisor : 1
info:  Queue families:
info:    Graphics : 0
info:    Transfer : 1
info:  DXVK: Read 0 valid state cache entries
info:  DXVK: Using 2 compiler threads
info:  DXGI: NvAPI workaround enabled, reporting AMD GPU
err:   D3D11DXGIResource::CreateSharedHandle: Stub
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.857:WARNING:offscreen_windowing_d3d11.cpp(259)] Couldn't create shared handle for test texture
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.875:WARNING:offscreen_window.cpp(70)] disabling gpu
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.875:INFO:offscreen_window.cpp(459)] OnSize w=1240 h=773 r=1
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.875:INFO:offscreen_window.cpp(415)] setting zoom to: 0
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.875:INFO:offscreen_renderer_d3d11.cpp(631)] Initializing osc d3d11 renderer to: 1240 773
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.879:INFO:cef_plugin_manager.cpp(171)] Loading all plugins
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.886:INFO:cefmain_win.cc(461)] CEF resource load time : 401ms
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.887:INFO:browser_app.cc(1083)] Start app event thread
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.893:INFO:cef_plugin_win.cpp(28)] Loaded dependency module discord-rpc.dll
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.896:INFO:ipc_api.cc(21)] Creating IpcApi
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.896:INFO:ipc_cef.cc(52)] Creating IPC instance with name = GeForceNOW, type = mallclient
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.897:INFO:json_storage_win.cc(33)] Lock opened an existing mutex so waiting on NvCrimson.ipcmessages.json
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.897:INFO:json_storage_win.cc(35)] Lock mutex aquired
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.897:INFO:ipc_cef.cc(74)] Finished initialization.
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.898:INFO:file_watcher_win.cc(344)] Detected file modified
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.898:INFO:json_storage_win.cc(33)] Lock opened an existing mutex so waiting on NvCrimson.ipcmessages.json
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.899:INFO:json_storage_win.cc(35)] Lock mutex aquired
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.899:INFO:ipc_cef.cc(159)] Found valid messages list of size 1 for client GeForceNOW (mallclient)
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.899:INFO:ipc_cef.cc(189)] Polling: There are 1 messages waiting for client GeForceNOW (mallclient)
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.899:INFO:osr_simple_handler.cpp(567)] SDL Foreground: Window is not minimized, bringing to front
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.899:WARNING:offscreen_layer.cpp(680)] creating browser layer: 1
wine: Unhandled page fault on execute access to 0000000000000000 at address 0000000000000000 (thread 0168), starting debugger...
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.928:INFO:cef_plugin_win.cpp(137)] Loaded Cef Plugin  cef/client/Discord.dll
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:28.968:INFO:cef_plugin_win.cpp(137)] Loaded Cef Plugin  cef/client/Gallery.dll
Unhandled exception: page fault on execute access to 0x00000000 in 64-bit code (0x0000000000000000).
Register dump:
 rip:0000000000000000 rsp:0000000000237e48 rbp:0000000000000005 eflags:00010206 (  R- --  I   - -P- )
 rax:00007f49b2bace00 rbx:0000000000000000 rcx:000000000f3bafb0 rdx:000000000f3bc160
 rsi:0000000008bc0660 rdi:000000000f3b9060  r8:0000000000000000  r9:0000000000238090 r10:000000000f3bbe20
 r11:000000000f3bbe20 r12:000000000475e5c0 r13:000000000f3b5480 r14:00000000002382a8 r15:0000000000238090
Stack dump:
0x0000000000237e48:  000000000475e650 0000000000000000
0x0000000000237e58:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000000237e68:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000000237e78:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000000237e88:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000000237e98:  0000000000000000 ffff000000000000
0x0000000000237ea8:  ffffffff00000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000000237eb8:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000000237ec8:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000000237ed8:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000000237ee8:  0000000000000000 000000000f3bc160
0x0000000000237ef8:  000000000f3bafb0 0000000000000000
Backtrace:
=>0 0x0000000000000000 (0x0000000000000005)
0x0000000000000000: -- no code accessible --
Modules:
Module  Address                 Debug info  Name (106 modules)
PE            240000-          253000   Deferred        aclui
PE            7e0000-          7e8000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-1
PE            c30000-          dca000   Deferred        gsaudiowebrtc
PE            dd0000-         17ff000   Deferred        bifrost2
PE           1800000-         180b000   Deferred        qwave
PE           1810000-         1f63000   Deferred        geronimo
PE           2080000-         217c000   Deferred        chrome_elf
PE           2180000-         9c59000   Deferred        libcef
PE           9c70000-         9cc1000   Deferred        oleacc
PE           9cd0000-         9cf7000   Deferred        credui
PE           9d00000-         9d13000   Deferred        esent
PE           9d20000-         a14e000   Deferred        d3dcompiler_47
PE           a150000-         a1b4000   Deferred        libegl
PE           a1c0000-         af7b000   Deferred        libglesv2
PE           dea0000-         e17d000   Deferred        crimsonutil
PE           e180000-         e4f6000   Deferred        gfnspfbc
PE           e630000-         e977000   Deferred        gfncapture
PE           eab0000-         f167000   Deferred        shareserver
PE           f9f0000-         ffc0000   Deferred        nvcamera
PE          119c0000-        11a5c000   Deferred        discord-rpc
PE          11bf0000-        11ec1000   Deferred        discord
PE          11ed0000-        12305000   Deferred        gallery
PE          61340000-        61347000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-localization-obsolete-l1-2-0
PE          61480000-        6148c000   Deferred        wlanapi
PE          61900000-        61929000   Deferred        sechost
PE          61f40000-        61f4e000   Deferred        wtsapi32
PE          62240000-        624d1000   Deferred        d3d9
PE          62540000-        62567000   Deferred        wintrust
PE          62600000-        6263c000   Deferred        usp10
PE          62740000-        6274f000   Deferred        imagehlp
PE          628c0000-        628df000   Deferred        uiautomationcore
PE          637c0000-        63878000   Deferred        winmm
PE          638c0000-        638ce000   Deferred        dwmapi
PE          64340000-        64381000   Deferred        winhttp
PE          64940000-        64959000   Deferred        shcore
PE          64b80000-        64b8f000   Deferred        hid
PE          64d40000-        64d4f000   Deferred        vulkan-1
PE          65000000-        65142000   Deferred        ole32
PE          65680000-        65688000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-2-1
PE          65780000-        6578d000   Deferred        version
PE          66200000-        6626a000   Deferred        dbghelp
PE          66500000-        66532000   Deferred        rsaenh
PE          66600000-        66607000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-datetime-l1-1-1
PE          66780000-        66787000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-string-l1-1-0
PE          67880000-        67890000   Deferred        wpc
PE          67d00000-        67d0e000   Deferred        userenv
PE          67dc0000-        67dd0000   Deferred        cryptnet
PE          68140000-        68174000   Deferred        msctf
PE          68a40000-        68a91000   Deferred        shlwapi
PE          68f80000-        68f92000   Deferred        pdh
PE          69840000-        6984e000   Deferred        xinput1_4
PE          69c80000-        69caa000   Deferred        propsys
PE          6a100000-        6a235000   Deferred        oleaut32
PE          6a340000-        6a609000   Deferred        d3d11
PE          6a700000-        6a773000   Deferred        setupapi
PE          6b2c0000-        6b33c000   Deferred        wininet
PE          6b6c0000-        6b7bf000   Deferred        comdlg32
PE          6b880000-        6b887000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-fibers-l1-1-1
PE          6bd00000-        6bd0d000   Deferred        schannel
PE          6bec0000-        6bed8000   Deferred        imm32
PE          6c100000-        6c108000   Deferred        api-ms-win-appmodel-runtime-l1-1-2
PE          6c600000-        6c607000   Deferred        api-ms-win-security-systemfunctions-l1-1-0
PE          6d3c0000-        6d418000   Deferred        dsound
PE          6d9c0000-        6d9df000   Deferred        mpr
PE          6dcc0000-        6ddc6000   Deferred        cryptui
PE          6e280000-        6e28e000   Deferred        ncrypt
PE          6e340000-        6e348000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0
PE          6e6c0000-        6e804000   Deferred        comctl32
PE          6f200000-        6f3e1000   Deferred        dxgi
PE          6f480000-        6f505000   Deferred        gdiplus
PE          6fbc0000-        6fc41000   Deferred        rpcrt4
PE          70140000-        70165000   Deferred        mmdevapi
PE          70980000-        709a0000   Deferred        msdmo
PE          70a00000-        70a0c000   Deferred        dhcpcsvc
PE          71140000-        711db000   Deferred        urlmon
PE          71240000-        71260000   Deferred        jsproxy
PE          7a850000-        7a858000   Deferred        opengl32
PE          7b000000-        7b0d2000   Deferred        kernelbase
PE          7b610000-        7b7db000   Deferred        kernel32
PE          7bc20000-        7bc35000   Deferred        ntdll
PE         140000000-       140365000   Deferred        geforcenow
PE         180000000-       18011d000   Deferred        sdl2
PE      7f49a82a0000-    7f49a82a8000   Deferred        windowscodecs
PE      7f49a8390000-    7f49a839c000   Deferred        dinput8
PE      7f49b22c0000-    7f49b22de000   Deferred        wldap32
PE      7f49b27e0000-    7f49b27e4000   Deferred        winepulse
PE      7f49b2aa0000-    7f49b2aa4000   Deferred        kerberos
PE      7f49b2ac0000-    7f49b2acd000   Deferred        winspool
PE      7f49b2b20000-    7f49b2b24000   Deferred        dwrite
PE      7f49b2bd0000-    7f49b2bd6000   Deferred        dnsapi
PE      7f49b2c00000-    7f49b2c07000   Deferred        netapi32
PE      7f49b2c40000-    7f49b2c44000   Deferred        secur32
PE      7f49b2c90000-    7f49b2c94000   Deferred        dxva2
PE      7f49b2cd0000-    7f49b2ce0000   Deferred        msvcrt
PE      7f49b2e00000-    7f49b2e07000   Deferred        winevulkan
PE      7f49b2e50000-    7f49b2e56000   Deferred        iphlpapi
PE      7f49b3440000-    7f49b3445000   Deferred        bcrypt
PE      7f49b3470000-    7f49b34b7000   Deferred        crypt32
PE      7f49b3570000-    7f49b3575000   Deferred        uxtheme
PE      7f49b3c20000-    7f49b3c25000   Deferred        winex11
PE      7f49b3d00000-    7f49b45fb000   Deferred        shell32
PE      7f49b4750000-    7f49b4756000   Deferred        ws2_32
PE      7f49b47b0000-    7f49b48a1000   Deferred        user32
PE      7f49b4a30000-    7f49b4a3c000   Deferred        gdi32
PE      7f49b4be0000-    7f49b4bfe000   Deferred        ucrtbase
PE      7f49b4cf0000-    7f49b4cfb000   Deferred        advapi32
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
00000038 services.exe
    ["C:\windows\system32\services.exe"]
    0000003c    0
    00000040    0
    0000004c    0
    0000006c    0
    00000094    0
00000044 plugplay.exe
    [C:\windows\system32\plugplay.exe]
    00000048    0
    00000058    0
    0000005c    0
    00000060    0
    0000007c    0
    00000220    0
    00000224    0
    00000228    0
00000064 winedevice.exe
    [C:\windows\system32\winedevice.exe]
    00000068    0
    00000070    0
    00000074    0
    00000078    0
    00000088    0
0000008c winedevice.exe
    [C:\windows\system32\winedevice.exe]
    00000090    0
    00000098    0
    0000009c    0
    000000a0    0
000000ac explorer.exe
    [C:\windows\system32\explorer.exe /desktop]
    000000b0    0
    000000bc    0
    000000c0    0
    000000c4    0
00000164 (D) C:\users\carlos\Local Settings\Application Data\NVIDIA Corporation\GeForceNOW\CEF\GeForceNOW.exe
    ["C:\users\carlos\Local Settings\Application Data\NVIDIA Corporation\GeForceNOW\CEF\GeForceNOW.exe"]
    00000168    0 <==
    000001b8    0
    000001bc    0
    000001c0   -2
    000001c4    0
    000001c8    0
    000001cc    0
    000001d0    0
    000001d4    0
    000001d8    0
    000001dc    0
    000001e0    0
    000001e4    0
    000001e8    0
    000001ec    0
    000001f0    0
    000001f4    0
    000001f8    0
    00000204    0
    00000208    0
    00000210    0
    00000214    0
    00000218   -2
    0000021c    0
    0000022c    0
    00000230    0
    00000248    0
    0000024c    0
    00000254    0
    00000258    0
    0000025c    0
    00000260    0
    00000264    0
    00000268    0
    0000026c    0
    00000294   -2
    00000298   -2
    0000029c    0
    000002a0    0
    000002a4    0
    000002a8    0
    000002ac    0
    000002b0    0
    000002b4    0
    000002d0    0
    000002d4   -2
    000002d8    0
    000002dc    0
    000002e0    0
    000002e4    0
    000002f8    0
0000016c GeForceNOWReliabilityMonitor.exe
    ["C:\users\carlos\Local Settings\Application Data\NVIDIA Corporation\GeForceNOW\CEF\GeForceNOWReliabilityMonitor.exe"]
    00000170    0
    0000017c    0
    00000180    0
    00000184    0
    00000188    0
    0000018c    0
    00000190    0
    00000194    0
    00000198    0
00000174 GeForceNOWContainer.exe
    ["C:\users\carlos\Local Settings\Application Data\NVIDIA Corporation\GeForceNOW\CEF\GeForceNOWContainer.exe" -c -r -d "C:\users\carlos\Local Settings\Application Data\NVIDIA Corporation\GeForceNOW\CEF\nvc/localuser" -f "C:\users\carlos\Local Settings\Application Data\NVIDIA Corporation\GeForceNOW\logs\NvContainer\GeForceNOWContainer.log" -l 3]
    00000178    0
    000001b4    0
    0000020c    0
    00000234    0
    00000238    0
    0000023c    0
    00000240    0
000001fc GeForceNOW.exe
    ["C:\users\carlos\Local Settings\Application Data\NVIDIA Corporation\GeForceNOW\CEF\GeForceNOW.exe" --type=gpu-process --field-trial-handle=668,17301759913646658673,14657670472115525870,131072 --enable-features=CastMediaRouteProvider --disable-features=OutOfBlinkCors --no-sandbox --log-file="C:\users\carlos\Local Settings\Application Data\NVIDIA Corporation\GeForceNOW\debug.log" --log-severity=info --lang=en-US --gpu-preferences=MAAAAAAAAADgAAAwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABgAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKAAAAAQAAAAgAAAAAAAAACgAAAAAAAAAMAAAAAAAAAA4AAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGAAAAEAAAAAAAAAABAAAABQAAABAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAYAAAA= --use-gl=swiftshader-webgl --log-file="C:\users\carlos\Local Settings\Application Data\NVIDIA Corporation\GeForceNOW\debug.log" --mojo-platform-channel-handle=676 /prefetch:2]
    00000200    1
    00000250    0
    00000274    0
    00000278    0
    0000027c   -2
    00000280    1
    00000284    0
    00000288    0
    0000028c    1
    00000290    0
000002e8 GeForceNOW.exe
    ["C:\users\carlos\Local Settings\Application Data\NVIDIA Corporation\GeForceNOW\CEF\GeForceNOW.exe" --type=renderer --no-sandbox --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required --log-file="C:\users\carlos\Local Settings\Application Data\NVIDIA Corporation\GeForceNOW\debug.log" --field-trial-handle=668,17301759913646658673,14657670472115525870,131072 --enable-features=CastMediaRouteProvider --disable-features=OutOfBlinkCors --disable-gpu-compositing --lang=en-US --log-file="C:\users\carlos\Local Settings\Application Data\NVIDIA Corporation\GeForceNOW\debug.log" --log-severity=info --device-scale-factor=1 --num-raster-threads=2 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=3 --mojo-platform-channel-handle=1628 /prefetch:1]
    000002ec    0
System information:
    Wine build: wine-4.11-7296-g60ed72fc8f (Staging)
    Platform: x86_64
    Version: Windows 7
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 5.4.0-52-generic
Initial process has exited.
[3920-11-01/ 11:11:29.530:ERROR:broker_win.cc(55)] Error reading broker pipe: Tubera rota. (0x6D)
2020-11-01T11:11:27.822[I]                     LoggingImpl.cpp:203  Initialize CrimsonNative logger
```

Comment: Esta áerea es exclusivamente para respuestas, agregar información de tu pregunta aquí, no es correcto. Saludos